# Adjust shape stroke position on Squares/Triangles

Tags: konvajs

I need to set the stroke position on Squares (Rect class) and Triangles (Line class) like it was done for Circles here:
[GitHub issue with example](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/438)

I want to use the first solution using the `sceneFunc`. It's very hard for me to figure out how to do the same for Squares and Triangles.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const square = new Konva.Shape({
  x: 50,
  y: 30,
  stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  strokeWidth: 20,
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  sceneFunc: (ctx, shape) => {
    ctx.rect(0, 0, shape.width(), shape.height());
    // first stroke
    ctx.strokeShape(shape);
    // then fill
    ctx.fillShape(shape);
  }
});
layer.add(square);

const triangle = new Konva.Shape({
  x: 250,
  y: 30,
  stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  strokeWidth: 20,
  fill: 'green',
  draggable: true,
  sceneFunc: (ctx, shape) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 100);
    ctx.lineTo(-50, 100);
    ctx.closePath();
    // first stroke
    ctx.strokeShape(shape);
    // then fill
    ctx.fillShape(shape);
  }
});
layer.add(triangle);
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/fumacupoku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot! I hope to understand it someday... I'll take my time to investigate it.